# Is there a function to isolate rows of data based on the distance between the start and stop of their GPS coordinates?

Tags: r, gps, subset, latitude-longitude

Budding ecologist here learning how to use R studio in data analysis. I'm research bison movements in the GYE to show where they cross highways - the data was stored on google looker studio after being transferred from old home-baked software. There are two types of sightings - static sightings and ones with a start and stop that show movement.

I need to isolate the rows that have start and stop data from the static ones in R, but the issue is that both static and start-stop rows have beginning and end linestring pathway data ( Ex: "LINESTRING(-111.097913 44.776748, -111.097813 44.776748)" ) - the static rows just have a negligible difference of 0.0001° for the longitude specifically, whereas the rows that show actual movement it's much greater. The latitude is consistent for static rows.

Is there a function that can separate row data based on the disparity between the two linestring longitude data points? I am a novice at R, taking lessons/exercises to build my skills so I'm not sure where to start for a function like this, but it seems possible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried to create vectors with concatenated information based on the "LINESTRING" column, using subset(), but I couldn't find a way to isolate the data based on this kind of rule.

Comment: Hi Jackson Doyel, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. For you, that most likely means subsetting a few rows of your data ensuring a couple of static and movement records are included, and then running `dput()` on your subset and adding the result to your question. Thanks

Comment: If all the pathway data is of that pattern ( `LINESTRING(lat1 long1, lat2 long2)` ), I'd try breaking it out into separate columns, then applying your logic to that

Comment: Calculate the distance of the start/stop with `sf::st_distance()`; if the 'static' entries have same start/stop positions, the distance will be 0 or close to 0. Filter out those.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sf::st_distance()` between start/stop points or `sf::st_length()` on linestrings itself, like:

```r
data.frame(
  geom = c("LINESTRING(-111.097913 44.776748, -111.097813 44.776748)", 
           "LINESTRING(-111.097913 44.776748, -111.097813 44.776848)", 
           "LINESTRING(-111.097913 44.776748, -111.097813 44.716748)"),
  n = c(1, 2, 3)
  ) |>
  sf::st_as_sf(wkt = "geom", crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
  dplyr::mutate(length = sf::st_length(geom))
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -111.0979 ymin: 44.71675 xmax: -111.0978 ymax: 44.77685
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   n                           geom          length
#> 1 1 LINESTRING (-111.0979 44.77...    7.893258 [m]
#> 2 2 LINESTRING (-111.0979 44.77...   13.636236 [m]
#> 3 3 LINESTRING (-111.0979 44.77... 6671.710745 [m]
```

and filter out those 'static' like:

```r
[...]
  dplyr::mutate(length = sf::st_length(geom)) |>
  subset(length >= units::as_units(15, "m"))

#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -111.0979 ymin: 44.71675 xmax: -111.0978 ymax: 44.77675
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   n                           geom       length
#> 3 3 LINESTRING (-111.0979 44.77... 6671.711 [m]
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-04 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>